# UnsupportedOperationException When Inserting into Map

Tags: apache-spark, collections, hashmap

I am using the Spark's `collectAsMap` function [[Spark CollectAsMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29805527/spark-collectasmap]) to obtain a Map. In this map, when I do the `put` operation I am getting the following exception:

```
ERROR ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.AbstractMap.put(AbstractMap.java:209)
```

Is the map obtained from collectAsMap unmodifiable?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I assume you are working in Java. You are getting this error because in java spark, `collectAsMap` returns a java wrapper around a scala map. In Spark 2.2, this wrapper is a custom class defined [in this source file](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaUtils.scala). As you can see, it does not define the `put` method, hence your error.

A workaround could be to simply copy the map into a java `HashMap` as follows

```java
List<Tuple2<Integer, Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new Tuple2<>(1,2));
list.add(new Tuple2<>(3,4));
Map<Integer, Integer> map = sc.parallelize(list)
    .mapToPair( x -> x )
    .collectAsMap();
    
Map<Integer, Integer> newMap = new HashMap<>(map);
newMap.put(7, 8);
System.out.println(newMap);
```

That yields the expected `{1=2, 3=4, 7=8}`.